# Data Source Explorer TAB missing in Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am following a tutorial to set up mysql database and do some stuff.
I am not able to find Data Base Explorer.
I read a lot but cant fine in Window->show View-> Dataxxx or in the Right side upper tab.
[image]

Comment: That view is part of Eclipse DTP. Do you have that installed?

Comment: Thanks , got it , Installed DTP sdk :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing DTP from Help->InstallNewSoftware ->Search DTP ->install solves the issue , Thanks @Greg-449